# checkbox jquery or javascript oncheck?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do not know the correct terminology for this, but I want the same effect as onclick but for a check box with jquery or javascript.

onclick version:

```
<a href="..." onclick="function()">Link</a>
```

I want the same effect as above but for a checkbox. The end result will be that the page should reload with an updated php query, but that part I can do. I just don't know what the onclick is for checkboxes.

checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="change" value="one" />changes php query
```

Answer (score 55):

You should listen to the `change` event, as the checkbox can be selected or deselect with the keyboard too:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="change"]').change(function() {
     if(this.checked) {
         // do something when checked
     }
 });
```

Similarly with plain JavaScript:

```
// checkbox is a reference to the element

checkbox.onchange = function() {
     if(this.checked) {
         // do something when checked
     }
};
```

And last, although you really should not use inline event handlers, but if you have to:

```
<input ... onchange="handler.call(this)" />
```

where `handler` is like the handlers shown above.

---

**Further reading:**

- [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)
- [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)
- [quriksmode.org Introduction to Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)

Comment: +1, you could also toggle the checkbox by clicking a matching label, which the other answers don't consider. This is definitely the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#input_id').click(function() {
    // do what you want here...
});
```

Comment: will the function run when a checkbox is checked and unchecked?

Comment: It will run when you just click, no matter if you check or uncheck.

Comment: I know it wasn't part of the original question, but it might be worth mentioning that if you have a matching `label` that goes with your checkbox, you'll also need to add a `.click()` function there as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input:checked').click(function() {
   //do something
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ and http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/