# Verifying if a checkbox is checked - what's wrong with the code?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple form:

HTML:

```
<form>
   <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio-button" value="male" class="file">Choose a picture from file<br>
   <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio-button" value="female" class="choose">Use example picture<br>
 </form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if($('#radio1').is(':checked')) { 
       alert("it's checked"); 
   }
 });
```

When I check #radio1 nothing happens, no alert, no errors in the console, what's going on?

Comment: That checkbox is not checked, so no alert gets showed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing if the radio button is checked *when the DOM is ready* and not *when the checked status changes*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#radio1').on('change', function () {
       if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
           alert("it's checked"); 
       };
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your JS executes only once when document is ready: the checkbox is then unchecked. You need to handle the click on the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you are only checking if it's checked when the document is loaded.
You should attach an event handler to the checkbox to see when that state changes.
Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7236837/146513